# Oracle SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, varchar

How can I do a constraint that will check first two values and second two values in different ranges? I have to put time in database, but i do not need a data, that's why I don't want to use DATETIME type. I need only a TIME, but as far as I know there is no TIME datatype in Oracle.

My column looks like:

```
visit_hours VARCHAR(4)
```

so the first 2 characters will be 00 to 23, and the second 2 characters will be 00 to 59, so I can store a time from 00:00 to 23:59.

How can I do that? I already found something like regular expressions, but I don't know how to implement it in this example.

```
CONSTRAINT check_time CHECK (regexp_like(visit_hours, '?????') );
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do something like

```
CONSTRAINT check_time CHECK( to_number( substr( visit_hours, 1, 2 ) ) BETWEEN 0 AND 23 AND
                             to_number( substr( visit_hours, 3, 2 ) ) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 );
```

`substr( visit_hours, 1, 2 )` gives you the first two characters in the string, `substr( visit_hours, 3, 2 )` gives you the third and fourth character.  Convert both to numbers with the `to_number` function and then verify the range.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to put time in database, but i do not need a data, that's why I don't want to use DATETIME type

You don't have to worry about `date` and `time` portion separately. A `DATE` data type will have both the portions and all you need is use `to_char` with proper `format model`.

So, you can have the column as -

`visit_hours DATE`

**Edit** As Jeffrey and Ben said, the constraint is not needed when data type is `DATE`. Just follow what I explained above.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I should have explicitly written it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any constraint - just use the `DATE` datatype, it stores time values as well. Your application can extract the time using `TO_CHAR(visit_hours, 'HH24:MI')` and ignore the date part and the seconds part.